# Error getting path image from Download folder Android

Tags: android, file

I use this method to get the file path from uri:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

If I try to get the file path from an image file from gallery works perfectly. But, when I try to get the path file from an image file from Download folder, doesnt work. Any suggestions. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> I use this method to get the file path from uri

That is not going to work.

> If I try to get the file path from an image file from gallery works perfectly

Not on all devices and not for all images.

> Any suggestions

You seem to think that a `Uri` has to map to a file, that you can find out the path to that file, and that the path would be something that you can use.

None of those things is true.

*If* the scheme of the `Uri` happens to be `file`, *then* `getPath()` will be a filesystem path, pointing to a file that (presumably) you could access.

If the scheme is `content`, then the `Uri` can point to *anything*:

- A file on external storage that you could access
- A file on removable storage that you cannot access
- A file on internal storage of another app, that you cannot access
- An asset of another app, which is not a file
- A value from a `BLOB` column of a database, which is not a file
- A value that is generated on the fly, the way that this Web page is, which is not a file
- Content that will be streamed from the Internet, which is not a file on the device
- And so on

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` (and perhaps `openOutputStream()`) to work with the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare. Thank you very much for your really good answer. After selecting the image, the Uri is being passed back correctly. But when I try to get the actual path of that image on the donwload folder, it crashes. The problem seems to be specifically with this specific folder. I dont know how to manage with ContentResolver or openInputStream(). So, how i can get the actual location in this folder?

Comment: @agustincola: "how i can get the actual location in this folder?" -- you don't. You use the `Uri` to access streams associated with the content, using a `ContentResolver`. This should be covered in your Android app development book or course. It is also covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file.html).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I didnt ask properly becouse of my English. After had studied several options, finally i founded a good solution that works for me. I force opening gallery image, and user are not able to download from Donwload folder at any moment. I do the next in showFileChooser method:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.select_picture)),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

I hope it will be useful for somebody in the future.